# Xdebug setting different via web page from CLI

Tags: php, xdebug, fedora

In my `/etc/php.d/15-xdebug.ini`, I have `xdebug.mode` set to "debug" and it shows debug mode when I run `php -i`.

However a page with `phpinfo()` shows it running in develop. Also `xdebug.start_with_request` shows "yes" via CLI, while via web it shows "default".

Comment: Do you have seperate `php.ini` files for the CLI and WebServer

Comment: Only one php.ini. I had that thought too.

Comment: Are you sure, check `phpinfo()` on webserver and `php --ini` on the terminal

Comment: It should tell you in `phpinfo()` which configuration it loaded and from where. This info could be cached though, so make sure to restart services.

Comment: How about `/etc/php-cli.d` ?? Fedora (which is RHEL, too) should be set up alike that... while I think that there are only two modes available: `debug` and `coverage` (they can be switched on the fly). Since there isn't any `15-xdebug.ini` available, I'll have to close-vote this question.

Comment: `xdebug.start_with_request` appears to be irrelevant to the CLI (there's no client anyway), guess it's save to ignore, assuming that it works. When looking for the [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) I've just accidentally found a great hint for one of my own questions. Thanks for making me search :)

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad... On my Fedora 35 system I forgot that I went to PHP 8 and it now uses PHP-FPM. Restarting the php-fpm.service picked up the changes to XDebug. It's always the simple things that take the longest to resolve.